# Is there a way to automate checking for duplicates in a column and delete/notify as entering?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

So I'm working on a google sheet project where I and a few others will be keeping track of every movie we watch and then scoring it from 1-10. Since this is a long-term project, the list of movie titles will get quite long and I'm trying to think of a way to notify the inputter if the movie title they're writing already exists further up in their column. Assuming it's an if-statement of some sort but very new to excel and google sheets.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You can conditionally format the column to flag (highlight cell **red** if it exists in a list) duplicates for you.

Comment: Excel <> Google Sheets - which are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You might try to create validation rule for the range of cells. Right button click on the cell -> Data Validation...

Or see the link below for details

[Google sheet value validation](https://blog.sheetgo.com/google-sheets-features/validate-input-values-in-google-sheets/)

Same solution might be implemented for MS Excel sheets

Answer (score 0):

I have used conditional formatting for this. Lets say movie names are in column A. The below code would highlight duplicate entries.
=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1

The only issue is if there is a Typo in the movie name you could still end up whit duplicates.  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHven.png)